# How to customize chakra ui tab element. in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, chakra-ui

i want to add tab eliments active style i saw they have used aria-selected:true to apply the css style  in a class but i don't know how to override this style in react can anyone explain how can i overwrite this in react ?
Please See the right down side. for the style they have used
[image]

```
.css-y2jimx[aria-selected=true], .css-y2jimx[data-selected] {
color: var(--chakra-colors-blue-600);
border-color: currentColor;}
```

> I want to overwrite this code in my react element like this

```
 <Tab style={
          aria-selected? 'selected style':'not selected style'
        }     
      >Basics</Tab>
```

Answer (score 1):

Chakra-UI is very well documented, you'll find all you need on this page : https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/disclosure/tabs.

First choose your `variant`, then your `colorScheme`. At last you will maybe need the `_selected` props for the final touch : https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/disclosure/tabs#styling-the-tab-states-via-props